# JavaFX with Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am trying to connect two classes. One is main swing class and other is javafx web view in a swing frame. This is run perfectly but do not show the exact output. My URL is coming from my swing frame class.

```
public Instruction() {
    System.out.println("new url number is=="+newurl);
    System.out.println("token number is=="+first.tokennum);
    System.out.println("final link is="+FirstToken.finallink);
    frame1.add(panel);
    frame1.setSize(500,500);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            initfx(panel);
        }
    });
}


public void initfx(JFXPanel panel){
    Scene scene = createscene();
    panel.setScene(scene);
    geturl(FirstToken.finallink);
}
public Scene createscene(){
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene=new Scene(root);
    Text text = new Text();
    text.setX(50);
    text.setY(100);
    root.getChildren().add(text);
    return (scene);

}
public void geturl(String url){
    WebView web=new WebView();
    System.out.println("url is="+url);
    web.getEngine().load(url);

}
```

Comment: *"This is run perfectly but do not showing exact output."* What is the 'exact output'? What does it show instead? If images would be helpful in explaining, link to them.

Comment: It shows blank white scene in Jframe. Is this right code for javafx webview in swing frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the WebView that you create to the scene graph.  To fix it, have your `geturl` routine return your WebView and add that WebView to the group which forms the root of your scene.

If you don't understand, read the [Oracle tutorial on integrating a JavaFX WebView into Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) and review the accompanied [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/simpleswingbrowserjava.htm#CBBHEAII).

Example code:

```
public WebView geturl(String url){
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().load(url);
    return webView;
}

public void initfx(JFXPanel panel){
    WebView webView = geturl(FirstToken.finallink);
    Scene scene = createscene(webView);
    panel.setScene(scene);
}

public Scene createscene(WebView webView){
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    root.getChildren().add(webView);

    return scene;
}
```